# JUnit for Spring Integration Activator with return type Message<?>

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, spring-integration

I am trying to write a JUnit test cases. and I became clue less how can i write test case for the below method.
What all needs to be mocked.

```
@Autowired
private DoseService doseService;

public Message<List<Dose>> getAllDoses() {
    log.info("GET method");
    List<Dose> doseLst = doseService.getAllDoses();
    return MessageBuilder.withPayload(doseLst).setHeader("http_statusCode", 
HttpStatus.OK).build();
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking to your method I would say that only `DoseService` has to be mocked. Everything else looks good and you also don’t need the `Message` as an argument.

For mocking you can use a `@MockBean` from Spring Boot.

Comment: Yes correct, In this i don't need any input. But if i have to have the Message as input how can a build it. Let say Message<String> ?

Comment: Use the same `MesaageBuilder`!

Comment: Thank for your suggestions. I was able successfully write the test case for this

Answer (score 1):

I wrote my test case like below and it works fine.

```
@Test
public void testGetAllDoses() {
    List<Dose> doses = createDoses();
    Message<List<Dose>> msg = MessageBuilder.withPayload(doses)
          .setHeader("http_statusCode", HttpStatus.OK).build();
    when(doseService.getAllDoses()).thenReturn(doses);
    Message<List<Dose>> returned =doseServiceActivator.getAllDoses();
    assertThat(returned.getPayload()).isEqualTo(msg.getPayload());
}

private List<Dose> createDoses(){
    List<Dose> doses = new ArrayList<Dose>();
    Dose dose1 = new Dose();
    dose1.setDoseId(1);
    dose1.setDoseValue("80");
    Dose dose2 = new Dose();
    dose2.setDoseId(2);
    dose2.setDoseValue("120");
    doses.add(dose1);
    doses.add(dose2);
    return doses;
}
```