# Error Could not open ServletContext resource in jUnit Testing Spring Integration

Tags: junit, spring-integration, junit4

I am new to Spring Integration and I am trying to test the channel.
I have written a below code. but i am getting exception while testing it. Please help me in resolving that.

Spring Integration flow.

```
<int:channel id="reqGetAllMedChannel" />
<int:channel id="resGetAllMedChannel" />
<int-http:inbound-gateway
    request-channel="reqGetAllMedChannel"
    reply-channel="resGetAllMedChannel" supported-methods="GET"
    path="/getAllMedicines">

    <int-http:request-mapping
        consumes="application/json" produces="application/json" />
</int-http:inbound-gateway>


<int:service-activator
    ref="medicineServiceActivator" method="getAllMedicines"
    input-channel="reqGetAllMedChannel"
    output-channel="resGetAllMedChannel" />
```

Method which is getting invoked.

```
public Message<List<Medicine>> getAllMedicines() {
    log.info("GET request for Medicine");
    List<Medicine> medLst = medicineService.getAllMedicines();
    return MessageBuilder.withPayload(medLst).setHeader("http_statusCode", HttpStatus.OK).build();
}
```

Testing xml configuration

```
<import resource="classpath:medicineIntegration.xml"/>

<int:bridge input-channel="resGetAllMedChannel" output-channel="testOutput">
</int:bridge>

<int:channel id="testOutput">
<int:queue/>
</int:channel>
```

jUnit test case.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(locations= {"classpath*:Integration-Test.xml"})
public class MessageChannelTest {

@Autowired
private MessageChannel inputChannel;

@Autowired
private QueueChannel testChannel;

@Mock
private MedicineService medicineService;

@Test
public void testChannel() {
    List<Medicine> medicines = new ArrayList<Medicine>();
    Medicine medicine1 = new Medicine();
    medicine1.setMedName("Crocine");
    medicine1.setExpDate("01-01-2020");
    Medicine medicine2 = new Medicine();
    medicine2.setMedName("Paracetamole");
    medicine2.setExpDate("02-02-2020");
    medicines.add(medicine1);
    medicines.add(medicine2);
    when(medicineService.getAllMedicines()).thenReturn(medicines);
    inputChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("").build());
    Message<?> outMsg = testChannel.receive(1000);
    assertThat(medicineService).isEqualTo(outMsg.getPayload());
}
}
```

Below is the exception i am getting while testing the jUnit code. Please help me  and let me know if i am doing something wrong.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89) ~[.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41) ~[.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541) ~[.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763) ~[.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463) ~[.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209) ~[.cp/:na]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the exception your `medicineService` depends on the `MedicineRepository`. Since you just have a:

```
@Mock
private MedicineService medicineService;
```

You don't effect the application context and don't replace your `medicineService` bean definition.

If you really want just mock this `MedicineService` and replace it in the application context, you should consider to use a `@MockBean` from Spring Boot: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans

You also can just `@MockBean` for that `MedicineRepository` and your `MedicineService` will remain the same in the application context.

I have already suggested you something similar in other your question: [JUnit for Spring Integration Activator with return type Message<?>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53735359/junit-for-spring-integration-activator-with-return-type-message)

Comment: Thanks for the help. MockBean works fine. But now the test  case fails. As the method which is getting invoked doesn't take any parameter. I am not sure how to invoke it. For now i am getting Null value in the outMsg

Comment: Yes you have suggested. I was in habit of using Mock while my previous testing that why it was missed again by me. Will remember this now.

Comment: I think now it deserves as separate SO question, if you still have some problems with the further logic.

Comment: Thanks a lot now my test cases are working fine accept the test cases where the methos doesn't take any parameter. This one test is one of them.  I will try to have that in a saperate question.

Answer (score 0):

`MedicineRepository` is part of the mocked service, try adding it to test context using `@Spy` and `@Autowired`:

```
@Autowired
@Spy
MedicineRepository medicineRepository
```

Comment: Please, take a look into my answer.